# SLURM: How to run 30 jobs on particular nodes only?

Tags: slurm

You need to run, say, 30 srun jobs, but ensure each of the jobs is run on a node from the particular list of nodes (that have the same performance, to fairly compare timings).
How would you do it?

What I tried:

- `srun --nodelist=machineN[0-3] <some_cmd>` : runs `<some_cmd>` on *all* the nodes simultaneously (what i need: to run `<some_cmd>` on *one* of the available nodes from the list)
- `srun -p partition` seems to work, but needs a partition that contains exactly machineN[0-3], which is not always the case.

Ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update**: Version 23.02 has fixed this, as can be read in the Release notes: `Allow for --nodelist to contain more nodes than required by --nodes.`

---

You can **go the opposite direction** and use the `--exclude` option of `sbatch`:

```
srun --exclude=machineN[4-XX] <some_cmd>
```

Then slurm will only consider nodes that are not listed in the excluded list. If the list is long and complicated, it can be saved in a file.

**Another option** is to check whether the Slurm configuration includes ''**features**'' with

```
sinfo  --format "%20N %20f"
```

If the 'features' column shows a comma-delimited list of features each node has (might be CPU family, network connection type, etc.), you can select a subset of the nodes with a specific features using

```
srun --constraint=<some_feature> <some_cmd>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use -w option. Its tested in slurm version 17.11.10

For example:

```
srun -p partition  -w node10 hostname
```

Comment: using your way, is it possible to specify a *list* of nodes? (instead of one specific node)

Comment: yes, srun -p partition  -w node10,node11 hostname command returns the hostname of the 2 computenodes. You can also use regex  "-w node[10-11]"

Comment: ...but i don't need to run it on _both_ nodes, only to run on one, but from the list. ?? thanks. (unfortunately I cannot test it myself right now, because have no access to srun)

Comment: if you know the $hostname of the computenode that you want your job to work on, then srun -p partition -w $hostname command should be enough for you. If you have to define a nodelist like srun -p partition --nodelist  /path/to/nodelist and want to choose 1 node from that nodelist, that seems an inconvenient way to me and i never tried that if any mechanism exists. Actually when you choose your partition, you are using a nodelist which are defined in that partition. then -w let you choose one or multiple computenodes you would like to use.